# M:N relationships on Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, relational-database

I have a webapp, done in Laravel 4, where users create and vote on polls. This is the migrations (simplified):

**Migration for polls:**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('polls', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('topic');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Migration for users:**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now:

I want to keep record when a users votes on a polls (so they can not vote again).

I guess I should do some sort of M:N table. Kinda like this:

```
| User ID | Poll ID   |
|---------|-----------|
|       1 |         5 |
|       1 |         7 |
|       1 |         8 |
|       3 |         5 |
|     ... |       ... |
```

But Laravel uses Eloquent ORM, and I have read there are functions like `belongsToMany` or `hasMany`. So, I was wondering:

Is there any convention or "clever" way to set up this kind of "relation tables" to simplify development and maintenance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you need 3 tables to get a many to many relationship working. the functions `belongsToMany` are just telling eloquent how to make the fetch the data.

if you're using [jeffrey way's laravel generator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) package, you can simply use the following command for the creation of the linking table.

```
php artisan generate:pivot polls users
```

then in your models add accordingly

```
// poll model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}

// user model
public function poll()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Poll');
}
```

Comment: This is quite badass :) Is there a way to auto-populate the M:N table? or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: i'd do that with [seeds](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding) and add them however you like (e.g. `$poll->users()->saveMany($users)` etc. there are several possibilities)

Comment: I thought seeding was about giving initial values to the database. Im not sure what it has to do with this problem.

Comment: Also, how do I add polls in where the user has voted, without deleting the ones I already have registered? And how would I "delete" the record of user in a certain poll, without deleting them all?

Comment: then i misunderstood that *auto-populate*, sorry. but still, that `saveMany()` should take care of populating the pivot table.

Comment: for specific removing a single entry from the pivot you can use `$poll->users()->detach($user_id)`